# How do you restore a .aff disk image to another hard drive?

Tags: disk-image

I've got a failed hard drive which I've managed to create a .aff image of. I would now like to restore this image to a working hard drive.

I can't seem to easily locate any software which makes this possible.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify what OS you are working on.

Anyway, AFFLIB is available for both windows and linux. http://www.fileinfo.com/extension/aff

You could also try and mount it in windows with http://www.osforensics.com/tools/mount-disk-images.html